# Cambiar primary Key en ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Buen dia, lei varios post y varias paginas que hablan que esto no es recomendable, de hecho arroja error al traer un registro, cambiarle la clave y guardar. Les dejo el codigo:

```
 List<Model> registroAUpdatear = (from s in db.Model where s.Id == IdAnterior select s).ToList();

        for (var i = 0; i < registroAUpdatear.Count; i++)
        {
            registroAUpdatear[i].Id = IdNuevo;
            db.Model.Add(registroAUpdatear[i]);
        }
```

Esto produce una excepción:

> "The property is part of the object's key information and cannot be
>   modified."

Entiendo que hay una forma de realizarlo, o mejor dicho 2 formas:

1-Crear un stored procedure que realize el alta y la baja desde la BD y llamarlo con entity framework.

2-Hacer un new Model(), pasandole los atributos del modelo a modificar, uno por uno y luego añadir la key nueva.

El problema es que estas 2 opciones demoran mucho para la cantidad de modelos tengo que modificar. A alguien se le ocurre otra alternativa? En lo posible que haya pasado por la misma situacion. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu escenario?

Comment: No quiero detallar mucho por que los tendria horas y horas... imaginate que llevo 10 mil lineas de codigo a mano + librerias y otras auto generdas.Ya encontre la solucion: basicamente tendria que crear 2 "List", uno de "AUpdatear" y otro de "ABorrar" y cargarlos antes de cualquier accion. Luego recurrir al For each de Baja, hacer SaveChanges, luego el For each de Update, hacer SaveChanges y listo. Recien lo probe y funciona.

Comment: ya listo :D entonces, agrega el comentario como respuesta, espera 24 horas y acepta tu respuesta. Así ayudas a mantener la salud del sitio mediante % de preguntas resueltas. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre la solucion: basicamente tendria que crear 2 "List", uno de "AUpdatear" y otro de "ABorrar" y cargarlos antes de cualquier accion. Luego recurrir al For each de Baja, hacer SaveChanges, luego el For each de Update, hacer SaveChanges y listo. Recien lo probe y funciona.

```
List<NombreDelModel> modelAUpdatear = (from s in db.NombreDelModel where s.Id== IdViejo select s).ToList(); 
List<NombreDelModel> modelABorrar = (from s in db.NombreDelModel where s.Id== Id select s).ToList(); 
for (var i = 0; i < modelABorrar.Count; i++) 
  { 
    db.NombreDelModel.Remove(modelABorrar[i]);
  } 
db.SaveChanges(); 
for (var i = 0; i < modelAUpdatear .Count; i++) 
  {
    modelAUpdatear [i].Id = IdNuevo2; 
    db.NombreDelModel.Add(modelAUpdatear[i]); 
  }
```

Tener en cuenta que, en caso de haber relación por primarykey/foreignkey primero se borra desde la última *foreign key* hacia la primera *primary key* pero se *updatea* desde la primera *primary key* hacia la última *foreign key*, y obviamente todos los List se cargan al principio, antes de cualquier acción. La verdad es un código interesante, busque en varios sitios y a nadie se le había ocurrido.

Comment: Creo que tu respuesta podría beneficiarse enormemente si publicaras el código que usaste

Comment: List<NombreDelModel> modelAUpdatear = (from s in db.NombreDelModel where s.Id== IdViejo select s).ToList();

List<NombreDelModel> modelABorrar = (from s in db.NombreDelModel where s.Id== Id select s).ToList();

 for (var i = 0; i < modelABorrar.Count; i++)
  {
 db.NombreDelModel.Remove(modelABorrar[i]);
 }
  db.SaveChanges();
 for (var i = 0; i < modelAUpdatear .Count; i++)
  {
 modelAUpdatear [i].Id = IdNuevo2;
 db.NombreDelModel.Add(modelAUpdatear[i]);
 }

Comment: Tener en cuenta que, en caso de haber relacion por primarykey/foreignkey primero se borra desde la ultima foreign key hacia la primera primary key pero se updatea desde la primera primary key hacia la ultima foreign key, y obviamente todos los List se cargan al principio, antes de cualquier accion. La verdad es un codigo interesante, busque en varios sitios y a nadie se le habia ocurrio. siempre encantado de ayudar. Perdon la demora pero los fines de semana no entro. Saludos

Comment: @seojedaperez: El código y las observaciones relevantes deben incluirse en la publicación, en este caso la respuesta. Lo he pasado y he dado algo de formato al código.